# BBEdit "Find" dialog

Tags: replace, bbedit

I find myself using BBEdit on a mac a lot during development (and pure text editing as well).  It's great and fulfills pretty much all of my needs.  However one really annoying thing I find with it is that the *Find* dialog closes automatically after the first match is found.  What I would much rather see is the dialog staying up with the "find" button highlighted, so that I could keep pressing "enter", "enter", "enter"... to get to the next, next, next... match.  Yet I'm force to press 'cmd-F' after every match to re-open the dialog.

Is there any way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> for next and <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> for previous match then the window will not close.

Comment: Ok, this is the closest there is; unfortunately, I'm very quick to press "enter" when I put something into the search box, but cmd-g seems to work even after the dialog is closed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution by using `Search -> Live Search` dialogue instead of `Search -> Find...`. It allows multiple enter hits to search for the next occurrence, though it has fewer options. Then, if you want, you can change in `Settings -> Menus & Shortcuts` the hotkey for **Live Search** to `CMD + F`, and for **Find...** to `^ + CMD + F`.